# Different layout for 1st and rest pages of report

Tags: birt

I currently have a detailed report to design:
A report which has different header-footer-detail for the first and rest of the pages. I tried to overcome the challange by using 2 Master Pages (not quite achieved anything yet) but I am stuck at the point which row count of 1st and rest of the pages... 1st page has 20 rest of the pages have 35 rows. Namely the question is:
"How can I set different pagebreak intervals for the table for each page?"

PS: BIRT version: 3.7

Edit: I've tried to create a group on row number and put a filter on row number to maintain flow between 2 different tables but no luck. (It didnt make real sense to put row filter but tried anyway :))

Answer (score 0):

What you may need to do in the body section of your report is create a grid of one column and two rows.  In the advanced properties for the upper cell, look under the section property for the Master Page setting, set that value equal to the name of your first master page.  Place your report contents in that cell and set the master page references to your first master page as well.  Repeat this for the second cell and references to the second page.  Your table(s) have an advanced property for page break interval that you can adjust to control how many rows go on a page.

However if you want your table data to flow continuously from the first page into the second page and onward, I am not sure if this is possible but will update my answer if I find a way.

Comment: Indeed the data rows are expected to flow continuously. (ie. 1st page has 1-20 rows of same dataset 2nd page has 21-55 rows of same dataset and so on).

Comment: I haven't found a way to do that yet.  I'll look into it if I find time.

Comment: @MadMAxJr That is the default behavior of binding a data set to a table